# EasyPhpThumbnail dynamic cropping

Tags: php, html

I'm building gallery on PHP. 
I decided to integrate EasyPhpThumbnail into my project.

The problem I'm having is set-up.

Maybe some has used this Class before and can share experience. If any suggestions with other class - I'll gladly hear them.

I want to dynamically crop the image that was uploaded. I'd like to set thumbnail size to specific width and height.

Any suggestions?

My Code now looks like this:

```
$thumb = new Classes_Images_EasyThumbMaker();
$thumb -> Cropimage = array(1,0,20,20,35,35);  // maybe something should be set here.                               
$thumb -> Thumbwidth = 205;
$thumb -> Thumbheight = 156;
$thumb -> Quality = 100;
// Full path to the images
$pathToImage = 'uploads/portfolio/original/' . basename($form->image->getFileName());
//$thumb -> Chmodlevel = '0755';
$thumb -> Thumblocation = 'uploads/portfolio/thumb/';
$thumb -> Thumbprefix = 'thumb_';
// Create the thumbnail and save it
$thumb ->Createthumb($pathToImage, 'file');
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the absolute path to your files, something like this:

```
// Your full path to the images
$dir = str_replace(chr(92),chr(47),getcwd()) . 'uploads/' ;
```